# How to prove that $\sigma_{ap}(T)$ is non empty?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I have a question concerning the approximate point spectrum of an operator.

Let $T$ be a bounded linear operator of a complex Hilbert space $H.$ The approximate point spectrum of $T$ is the set of all values $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that there exists a sequence of unit vectors $u_n\in H$ so that $\|(T-\lambda)u_n\|\to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$ We denote this set by $\sigma_{ap}(T)$. We denote the well-known spectrum of $T$ by $\sigma(T)$. It is know that $\sigma(T)$ is non empty and that $\sigma_{ap}(T)\subset\sigma(T)$

**My question :** Can we prove that $\sigma_{ap}(T)$ is non empty?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The boundary of $\sigma(T)$ is contained in the approximate point spectrum.

Comment: Is there a reference of this proof? Thanks

Comment: I am pretty sure that some of the textbooks in functional analysis contain that result. I was unable to find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Ryszard Szwarc in the comments, the boundary of the spectrum is always contained in the approximate point spectrum, so the latter is non-empty. This result is Proposition VII.6.7 in Conway's book *A Course in Functional Analysis*.

Comment: I don't have this book